# How to load only upi apps installed in device in android studio

Tags: android, android-manifest, upi

I tried using query packages also added intent filters in manifest but all applications are showing i need only upi applications

Answer (score 5):

Try the below code.

```
    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    mainIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri1 = new Uri.Builder().scheme("upi").authority("pay").build();
    mainIntent.setData(uri1);
    final List pkgAppsList = 
    context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < pkgAppsList.size(); i++) {
        ResolveInfo resolveInfo = (ResolveInfo) pkgAppsList.get(i);
        Log.d("TAG", "packageName: " + resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
        Log.d("TAG", "AppName: " + resolveInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
        Log.d("TAG", "AppIcon: " +resolveInfo.loadIcon(packageManager));
    }
```

. If your app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or higher, the system makes some apps visible to your app automatically, but it hides other apps by default.
so to work for OS 11 and above,
include the 'queries' element as below.

```
   <queries>
      <intent>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

         <data
             android:host="pay"
             android:scheme="upi" />
      </intent>
   </queries>
```

Comment: Hey, using this approach I'm getting apps where I have not linked my bank account. Is it possible to only get apps where I have linked my bank account?

Comment: Not working. Is it working in your phone?

Comment: yes @Dev4Life . it works. it was tested on Nokia and Samsung.

Comment: It's not working in my Pixel 6 Android 13. So....

Answer (score 0):

Please reconsider the architecture for payments. I would incorporate the payment API you're using and then let it handle payments rather than manually finding what apps are installed on the device.

There is no direct way to find all the payment apps. Still, if you want to go this route, you can maintain an exhaustive list of all the payment apps and check which apps are installed on the device. Here, you will have to constantly update and maintain the list of payment apps.